# Not able to redirect to url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, clio-api

I am using clio based authentication...

```
        var params = {
            response_type : 'code',
            client_id : 'abcdefghijklmanopqrstvuwxyz',
            redirect_uri : 'http://localhost:5000/welcome'
        }
        $http.get("https://app.clio.com/oauth/authorize",{
            params : params
        }).then(function (response) {
            window.location="https://app.clio.com/session/new";
        })
```

When we provide credentials in clio's login page, it will default redirect to "redirect_uri" specified above.

My angular state is defined as :

```
    STATE: 'welcome',
    URL: '/welcome?code',
    CONTROLLER: 'WelcomePageController',
    TEMPLATEURL: 'app/partials/welcome/welcome.html'
```

So Now after authorization, clio is redirecting to url as

> http://localhost:5000/welcome?code=abcdefghijkl

But my page is displaying as :

> Cannot GET /welcome

Answer (score 0):

change your url: to url:'/welcome'